# Select MAX DATE from joined Table

Tags: sql-server, join, date

I have two tables, PROJECT and BILLINGS, as follows:

```
Project_ID  Project_Client
----------  ------------------
P1          ABC Company
P2          DEF Company
P3          GHI Company

Proj_ID     Bill_Date   Bill_Amount
----------  ----------- -----------
P1          01-01-2013  123.45
P1          11-01-2013  234.56
P2          08-15-2013  345.67
P2          09-15-2013  456.78
P3          07-31-2013  567.89
```

I want to return the list of Projects and Project Clients only for projects that have billings AFTER 09-01-2013. How do I do the proper JOIN to do this?

Comment: The proper JOIN would be on the Project ID, but if you are looking for a full query, could you tell us what kind of SQL you are dealing with? MSSQL? MySQL?

Comment: It's MSSQL...sorry!

Comment: Also, the primary table is PROJECT (as there are already multiple JOINs from it).

Comment: Also are you looking for a cumulative total bill amount for the project?

Comment: No, actually just a list of Project_ID and Project_Client that have a billing on 9/1/2013 or later.

Comment: Note that I edited the BILLINGS.Project_ID to be BILLINGS.Proj_ID for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get just project id and clients (which are both on project table) there is no need to join Billings :

```
SELECT p.Project_ID, p.Project_Client 
FROM  PROJECT p 
    WHERE EXISTS 
      (
         SELECT NULL FROM BILLINGS b WHERE b.Project_ID = a.Project_ID 
         AND b.Bill_Date > 'your_date'
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
    a.[Project ID]
    , a.[Project Client]
FROM PROJECT a
INNER JOIN BILLINGS b
    ON a.[Project ID] = b.[Proj_ID]
WHERE b.[Bill Date] > '09-01-2013'
```

Comment: Excellent! And that won't return multiple records if there are multiple billings >= 9/1/13?

Comment: It could, but that's not the data as represented in the given BILLINGS table. The query could be made into a `SELECT DISTINCT` to combat that.